# Obtain original File extentions using PHP

Tags: php

I have a file abc.xls , and I need to upload a .csv file , I rename the file and upload it to bypass the extension validation which is a loop hole for my system, Is there any way using PHP to find original file extension or File extension at create time?

Comment: Unless you can find a way to detect the mime type, I'm thinking no.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$file_info = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($file_info, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
finfo_close($file_info);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no latent information which stays in the file or anything like that. What you should do is detect the MIME type of the file, regardless of what its name (including extension) is, e.g. with [Finfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php).

Answer (score 0):

use mime type on [fleinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)...

this is Already returned real file type

Answer (score -1):

No. The information is never sent to the server, so PHP has no way to get it. Even if it could, that wouldn't help much. I could create an Excel format file and save it with a `.csv` extension without ever saving it with a `.xls` extension.

You could try using [Fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) to guess at what type of data is in the file, but you've no way to find out what it was called.